# Should I do anything about unsupported packages after `do-release-upgrade`?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, do-release-upgrade

I just upgraded my WSL installation from 16.04 to 18.04, but don't know what to do about the following line in the upgrade prompt:

```
4 installed packages are no longer supported by Canonical. You can
still get support from the community.
```

I checked the details, so I have a list of the unsupported packages — gcc-5-base, gcc-6-base, subversion, and tcpd in my case — but I haven't been able to find anything online regarding what I'm supposed to *do* with this information.

Should I remove those packages?  Replace them with something else?  Just ignore the fact that they're no longer supported?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have nothing to worry about but you can double check with command:

```
$ apt list | grep -E 'gcc-.?-base'

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

gcc-5-base/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12 amd64 [installed]
gcc-6-base/xenial,now 6.0.1-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

In above case it's a Ubuntu 16.04 installation and it is showing what you have lost. When you run the command the results should show what you have gained (newer versions) with the code name `bionic` instead of `xenial`.

`gcc` is the compiler for Ubuntu and most other Linux distributions. It is needed when certain drivers and applications are released in source code rather than binary format. `gcc` compiles that source code (which humans can read) into binary format for the machine to run.